# After logging in with google oauth2, when sending request from react to my nodejs api, req.isAuthenticated is false?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-oauth

**The oauth2 authorization works correctly, but when sending a post request from my React to the api, the req.isAuthenticated is false**
This is my api:

index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
const Post = require("./model/posts");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
require("./auth.js");
const connect = require("./connect.js");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "xxx",
    name: "sessionId",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    rolling: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:5173",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
connect();
// Define your authentication routes
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);
app.get(
  "/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: "/",
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:5173/createpost",
  })
);

// Example protected route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // Access user information through req.user
  //   res.json(req.user);
  res.send('<a href="/auth/google">Authenticate</a>');
});

app.get("/posts", async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find({});
  res.send(posts);
});

app.post("/createpost", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  const formData = req.body;
  
  
});

// Start the server
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

//////////////////////////////////////
auth.js:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("./model/users");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth2").Strategy;

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID:
        "967355229599-r8h015llsiagh8v8k4a4uaidca597abf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      clientSecret: "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",
      callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/google/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    async function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      await User.findOrCreate(
        { googleId: profile.id, displayName: profile.displayName },
        function (err, user) {
          return done(err, profile);
        }
      );
    }
  )
);

// Serialize user information into the session
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log(`serialized:${user.id}`);
  done(null, user);
});

// Deserialize user from the session
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log(`deserialuser:${user}`);
  done(null, user);
});
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////
React => CreatePost.jsx :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreatePost() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [expiry, setExpiry] = useState("");

  const sendFormData = async (formData) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/createpost", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("Form submitted successfully");
      } else {
        console.error("Form submission failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during form submission:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendFormData({ title, topic, message, expiry });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Title:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={title}
            onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Topic:
          <select
            value={topic}
            onChange={(event) => setTopic(event.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="health">Health</option>

            <option value="politics">Politics</option>

            <option value="sport">Sport</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Message:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />

        <label>
          Expiry date:
          <input
            type="Date"
            value={expiry}
            onChange={(e) => setExpiry(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button>Create</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreatePost;
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

I noticed after successful log in api redirects to "http://localhost:5173/createpost", but there is no cookie in my browser. I have no idea wehre the problem is?